# Is that possible to rename the file with sequence number using {1..10}

Tags: bash, rename, brace-expansion

I have doubt. I have to rename the file with sequence number 1 to 10. i am able to create a file with following parameter.

```
touch file.$(date +%Y).$$.{1..10}
```

But i can't rename the file using the following command. Why {1..10} is not taking.Because i want rename a file as. mv command will take {1..10} ?

```
file.201704.<PID>.1
file.201704.<PID>.2
.
.
.
.
```

so below command is right?

```
for file in $(ls);
do

mv $file file.$(date +%Y%m).$$.{1..10}
done
```

Comment: The `touch` command creates ten different files because that's what the brace expansion generates. I can't imagine that you want to create ten copies with a single `mv` so it is completely unclear what you are actually trying to accomplish here. Could you please [edit] your question to explain your goal? Including a precise error description would also be good form ("it doesn't work" how exactly?)

Comment: And [don't use `ls` for that](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#ls). In fact, [never use `ls` in scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Tangentially, see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells

Comment: I'll leave open, this seems a common mistake about {1..10} and shell expansion as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The brace expansion `{1..10}` will cause the command line to be expanded to include several arguments.

For example, the `touch` command line will be expanded to something like

```
touch file.2017.5878.1 file.2017.5878.2 file.2017.5878.3 file.2017.5878.4 file.2017.5878.5 file.2017.5878.6 file.2017.5878.7 file.2017.5878.8 file.2017.5878.9 file.2017.5878.10
```

before being executed.  This is ok since the `touch` utility takes any number of arguments on the command line. Note: this creates 10 files, not one file.

However, the `mv` utility have different semantics compared to `touch`. It expects one or several source files/directories and one single target file/directory at the end.

This means that when

```
mv $file $file.$(date +%Y%m).$$.{1..10}
```

is expanded to something like

```
mv file file.2017.5878.1 file.2017.5878.2 file.2017.5878.3 file.2017.5878.4 file.2017.5878.5 file.2017.5878.6 file.2017.5878.7 file.2017.5878.8 file.2017.5878.9 file.2017.5878.10
```

it's assumed that you want to move *all* the files, except for the last thing on the command line.  It furthermore expects the last thing on the command line to be a directory name (since you're moving multiple things).

It is unclear to me what you actually want to do in that loop, so I can't further comment on how to go about resolving this issue.

When it comes to the loop itself, *please* don't ever use the output of `ls` like that.  Instead, do

```
for file in ./*; do
    # process "$file"
done
```

The output of `ls` is for you to *look at*, it's not fit for consumption by a script for several reasons. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls

Also, always double-quote your variables.  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells